# ¿Cómo puedo calcular esta fórmula?

Tags: sql

En la query que quiero hacer necesito calcular el top 3 de usuarios según lo que indica la siguiente fórmula dada:

[image: s]

No comprendo cómo debo calcular esta fórmula a través de una Query (o varias).
Me resulta muy muy muy muy muy muy muy muy muy muy complicado.
Para dar más información, decir que utilizo el programa pgAdmin 4 con lenguaje SQL y por último, indicar que estas son las tablas de mi base de datos que se necesitan para calcular la fórmula anterior:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Apartment CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Apartment(
    listing_url VARCHAR(255),
    name_apart VARCHAR (255),
    description TEXT,
    picture_url VARCHAR (255),
    property_type VARCHAR(255),
    accomodates VARCHAR(255),
    bathrooms VARCHAR(255),
    bedrooms VARCHAR(255),
    beds VARCHAR(255),
    square_feet INT,
    country_code VARCHAR (255),
    maximum_nights VARCHAR(255),
    minimum_nights VARCHAR(255),
    ID_adress serial,
    ID_price serial,
    PRIMARY KEY (listing_url),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_adress) REFERENCES Adress(ID_adress),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_price) REFERENCES Price(ID_price)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Host CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Host(
    ID_host serial,
    host_url VARCHAR (255),
    listing_url VARCHAR (255),
    host_name VARCHAR (255),
    host_since DATE,
    host_about TEXT,
    host_response_time VARCHAR (255),
    host_response_rate VARCHAR (255),
    host_is_superhost VARCHAR (255),
    host_picture_url VARCHAR (255),
    host_listings_count VARCHAR (255),
    host_identity_verified VARCHAR (255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_host)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Verificates CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Verificates(
    ID_verification Integer,
    ID_host Integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_verification,ID_host),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_verification) REFERENCES Verification(ID_verification),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_host) REFERENCES Host(ID_host)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Verification CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Verification(
    ID_verification serial,
    host_verification VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_verification)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Price CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE Price(
    ID_price serial,
    price money,
    weekly_price money,
    monthly_price money,
    security_deposit money,
    cleaning_fee money,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_price)
);´´´
```

Comment: hola, podrias indicar que has intentado?

Comment: No sé si SQL está pensado para realizar los cálculos que pides, me parece que el cálculo es mejor hacerlo una vez obtenidos los datos. Con esto me refiero a que no le veo sentido a estructurar una consulta que realice dicho cálculo que colocas en la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Hola, coincido con @MauricioContreras SQL puede hacer los calculos pero hay otras formas de hacerlo. Si el requisito viene de un proyecto old school cuando todo se hacia en la base de datos, te recomiendo crear un procedimiento almacenado que solo haga los calculos y le pasas los parametros del query que tiene los valores. Espero estas ideas te ayuden a aclarar la solucion. Suerte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Chicos, lo que esta pidiendo, aunque parece complicado, se puede hacer facilmente en sql. Pero el problema es que no se donde estan todos esos campos (tengan en cuenta que eso es una sumatoria de campos.. algo asi como un sum en un group by;) )

Comment: yo entiendo que debería  hacer una tabla para ir guardando los valores del sumatorio y después una query para mostrar los datos de esa tabla, pero no sé muy bien como hacerlo.

Comment: @GASNOBLE ¿podrías añadir algunos datos de ejemplo y el resultado que esperas para esos datos en concreto? Así podremos comprobar si el resultado nos coincide